# Solving $x^{2n}-x^{2n-1}+1\ge 0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

Let $n$ be a positive integer. Find the real values of $x$ for which $x^{2n}-x^{2n-1}+1\ge 0$.
I tried factoring, but to no avail. I have no other idea about how to approach this.

Comment: This is always greater than zero (for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$). The minimum value of $f(x)=x^{2n}-x^{2n-1}+1$ occurs when $x=1-\frac1{2n}$. Try proving that $f(1-\frac1{2n})\gt0$ instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First note that if $x$ is negative, the inequality holds trivially, since $x^{2n}$ would be positive and $x^{2n-1}$ would be negative. Thus we only have to consider $x \geq 0$.

If $x = 0$, then the inequality holds. If $0 < x < 1$, then $0 < x^{2n} < x^{2n-1} < 1$, so $\lvert x^{2n} - x^{2n-1} \rvert < 1$. Thus, it follows that $x^{2n} - x^{2n-1} + 1 > 0$.

If $x \geq 1$, then $x^{2n} \geq x^{2n-1}$, so $x^{2n} - x^{2n-1} \geq 0$. Thus, $x^{2n} - x^{2n-1} + 1 \geq 1$. Thus, the inequality holds for all real $x$.

Comment: This is far more concise than my answer.